# Aparece error 500 (Internal Server Error) en dos páginas de mi proyecto

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

Hola equipo quiero pedirles el favor con lo siguiente:
Tengo alojada mi pagina web en un servidor gratuito que tiene como nombre infinityfree ya que mi proyecto es pequeño tengo una aplicación php con mysql en donde una pagina me sirve bien, pero las otras paginas que tienen el mismo código no me funcionan, depurando con el Inspeccionador de código de Google Chrome, me aparece el siguiente error:
GET http://mipagina.com/Trab.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
Viendo algunos tutoriales veo que lo arreglan configurando propiedades en otros hosting como lo es el liberador de opciones, o versión de php, o creando un archivo .httaccess
Pero al realizar lo anteriormente descrito me sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar

Comment: ¿Cómo podemos reproducir el escenario sin código y sin características del servidor? Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: revisa los log de apache o Nginx que genera el servidor, no se cual use tu hosting

Comment: Pon temporalmente estas 3 líneas al inicio de los scripts que fallan: `ini_set('display_errors', '1'); ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` luego guarda y ejecuta de nuevo y analiza los errores que aparecen en pantalla. Si no logras resolver los errores que allí te dice entonces pulsa en [edit], agrega los mensajes de error copiando/pegando el texto, no capturas de imagen y agrega el código que falla para que podamos ayudarte. Convendría que aprendas a depurar, buscando en los logs de errores. Lo indicado aquí es un método rápido, pero no el mejor necesariamente.